# haystack search for non primary field

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I would like to have any option of searching an indexed model from two different fields.  For example, sometimes search by name and other times search by occupation. Does someone know the right approach to take?  This is my current search_indexes.py file:

```
class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    occupation = indexes.CharField(model_attr='occupation')

    def prepare(self, obj):
        self.prepared_data = super(JobIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        self.prepared_data['text'] = obj.name
        return self.prepared_data
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(status='open')
site.register(Job, JobIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to use a SearchQuerySet with filters: http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchqueryset_api.html

In your case, it'd look something like:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet()

# Find people named Bob
sqs.filter(name="Bob")
# Find people who are developers
sqs.filter(occupation="developer")
# Or chain searches: Find developers named Bob
sqs.filter(occupation="developer").filter(name="Bob")
```